# Did Parashurama really curse Arjuna?

Tags: mahabharata, arjuna, parashurama

I found a story on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arjuna#Marriage_to_Draupadi)

> the name Arjuna is cursed by the sage Parashurama. After the defeating the mighty and evil king Kartavirya Arjuna aka Sahasra Arjuna, Sage Parashurama cursed that whosoever holds the name Arjuna will never become a king and always be a servant of others.[55]

Is the origin of this story in any scripture?

Comment: Information in Wikipedia is based on "Ramachandrashastri, K.S (1936). Harivamsha. Pune: Chitrashala Press." So that is where you can check.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. There no information about this incident except Wikipedia page. We can suggest a edit on Wikipedia. Parashurama cursed Karna that he will forget his skills and powerful weapons when it required.

Comment: Information in Wikipedia is based on "Ramachandrashastri, K.S (1936). Harivamsha. Pune: Chitrashala Press." Did you check there? If not, how can you say there is no information on this except Wikipedia?

Comment: Thanks sv for comment. I googled those names. I cannot find the incident about Parashurama curse to Arjuna. Also I can't find people talking about this incident on internet or anywhere. Give me a link or other source on the internet so I can believe You.